# C# ways to protect my database credentials

Tags: c#

I'm currently using the ConfigurationManager to protect my credentials

```
 string _conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["fluxConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

I was wondering if there were any better ways to protect my server credentials too the point where it's not even worth trying to break in through. I've seen that some people use an api through there website to retrieve the credentials or something along those lines. But not exactly sure how that would even work.

Comment: Do you monitor who has access to your production servers? Do you wish to encrypt the credentials from internal personnel?

Comment: @RossBush I'm currently using local at the moment, but I do plan purchasing a server when I'm completed but I might as well get this over with instead of doing it once I purchase the server.

Comment: You can use encryption on the config sections, however, anybody who can set a breakpoint in your code can see the credentials. You are better off just being a gatekeeper to the production box with your secured credentials. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx

Comment: You can just encrypt the connection strings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: @RossBush User's data is already encrypted, but I'm trying to find the best way to make it extremely difficult for the hacker to get my database credentials.

Comment: @Vince - Then simply encrypt the connection string using the technique suggested by RamblinRose above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the level of your concern.

Level 0: Do nothing

Most people add the credentials to the connection string in the web/app config and that's good enough. The only people who would steal the credentials are the ones that already have access to the server.

Level 1: Encryption

To protect the credentials from those who work for you can encrypt the connection string: [See MSDN for Connection String Encryption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2).

Level 3: Custom

You can create a [Web API Restful Web Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api) that reads the encrypted database credential from another database and returns it you in its encrypted form. You then call the web service from your code, decrypting the credentials it provides for you and thus build your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment:

> but I do plan purchasing a server when I'm completed

Besides encrypting the connection string, that actual configuration file is not where you start to secure the environment. Basically, the app does need to connect. So at some point, even when using a remote API (for which you need ... connection settings ..) the string must be available somewhere.

My suggestion:

Change the configuration settings during deployment. This way the production information is not ever present in the development environment.

I expect your production environment to have tons of other security measures next to finally reaching the configuration file.

A good example of a basic system to realize this is [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/).